# Is there a command that does exact numerical conversion of non-exact to exact numbers?

Tags: number-representation, big-numbers

I generally prefer to do all my intermediate calculations with exact numbers, and then round my result at the end. Thus I will typically convert each arbitrary-precision number to its exact equivalent; e.g., 1.7 becomes 17/10.   However, the only method I've found that ensures numerically exact conversion is the manual one:  delete the decimal point, and then divide by 10^z, where z is the number of digits to the right of the decimal.

For instance, consider `a = 399847593.00000068`.  If I use the above method, I get a fraction that is exactly equal to `a`.  Is there a command that achieves this?

Edit added for clarity:  I'm not looking for exact rational representations of the computer's internal binary representation of base-10 floating point numbers; I understand the latter typically can't be exactly equal to the floating point. Rather, I'm looking for exact rational representation of the floating point numbers themselves (which the software can do, if I enter them manually), which will then effectively be carried through the entire calculation. At the end of the calculation, final cancellations, and numerical conversion to a floating point, if desired, can then be done.

I tried `SetPrecision[a,Infinity]` and `SetAccuracy[a, Infinity]`, but both give fractions that are not exactly equal to `a` (see screenshot below).  Why is this? [Edit: I've removed my speculations here, since Szabloc's answer explains the behavior of these commands.]

From the name, `Rationalize` might seem to be a good candidate, but `Rationalize[a, 0]` likewise doesn't give a numerically exact conversion, as expected from the documentation: "`Rationalize[x,0]` gives a rational number equivalent to x up to the precision of x."  Finally, multiplying by 10^z (see first paragraph), applying `Floor`, and then dividing by 10^z likewise doesn't achieve the desired result:

[image]

```
{a = 399847593.00000068, Precision[a] // N}
mExact = 39984759300000068/10^8; (*manual method*)
mNum25 = NumberForm[N[mExact, 25], 
ExponentFunction -> (If[-Infinity < # < Infinity, Null, #] &)];
{mExact, Precision[mExact], mNum25}
pExact = SetPrecision[a, Infinity]; (*SetPrecision method*)
pNum25 = NumberForm[N[pExact, 25], 
ExponentFunction -> (If[-Infinity < # < Infinity, Null, #] &)];
{pExact, Precision[pExact], pNum25}
aExact = SetAccuracy[a, Infinity]; (*SetAccuracy method*)
aNum25 = NumberForm[N[aExact, 25], 
ExponentFunction -> (If[-Infinity < # < Infinity, Null, #] &)];
{aExact, Precision[aExact], aNum25}
rExact = Rationalize[a, 0]; (*Rationalize method*)
rNum25 = NumberForm[N[rExact, 25], 
ExponentFunction -> (If[-Infinity < # < Infinity, Null, #] &)];
{rExact, Precision[rExact], rNum25}
fExact = Floor[a*10^8]/10^8; (*Floor method*)
fNum25 = NumberForm[N[fExact, 25], 
ExponentFunction -> (If[-Infinity < # < Infinity, Null, #] &)];
{fExact, Precision[fExact], fNum25}
```

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136854/280

Comment: note 1.7 is only exactly 17/10 if you grab it on input before it gets converted to a binary representation. Maybe what you really want is simply Round ( with precision argument )

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/42141/2079

Answer (score 9):

> However, the only method I've found that ensures numerically exact conversion is the manual one: delete the decimal point, and then divide by 10^z, where z is the number of digits to the right of the decimal.

This does not produce an exact conversion because floating point numbers are represented in binary, not in decimal.

> I tried SetPrecision[a,Infinity] and SetAccuracy[a, Infinity], but both give fractions that are not exactly equal to a (see screenshot below).

In fact the result of `SetPrecision[..., Infinity]` is the one that is *exactly* equal to the input.  Floating point numbers are represented in binary.  You can see all their digits using [`RealDigits[..., 2]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RealDigits.html).

The following will give an exact conversion, and the same result as `SetPrecision[..., Infinity]` (thanks @george2079!)

```
exactConvert[x_Real] := FromDigits[RealDigits[x, 2], 2]
```

If you try it on `0.1`, you don't get `1/10`:

```
exactConvert[0.1]
(* 3602879701896397/36028797018963968 *)

SetPrecision[0.1, Infinity]
(* 3602879701896397/36028797018963968 *)
```

We don't get `1/10` because `1/10` is simply not exactly representable in binary.  When Mathematica prints it as `0.1`, it does some rounding.  This already shows that it does not make sense for most use cases to do a truly exact conversion.

[`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html) returns a more reasonable result:

```
Rationalize[0.1, 0]
(* 1/10 *)
```

The important thing to keep in mind is that floating point numbers are meant as an *approximate representation*.  For most use cases an exact conversion simply does not make sense.  However, if you do want to do it, you can using the functions above.

In my opinion, `Rationalize` with a reasonable chosen precision makes more sense.  For a machine number, a reasonable precision is something just below `$MachinePrecision`, i.e. about 15 digits.  This is why `Rationalize[0.1, 0]` gives `1/10` instead of the truly exact 
`3602879701896397/36028797018963968`.

---

To sum up, the key problem here is that your concept of "exactness" as taking all displayed decimal digits is simply flawed; and that true exactness is simply not useful unless you are concerned with floating point representations.

Comment: This seems to give the same result as `SetPrecision[x,Infinity]`. Are there cases where it does not?

Comment: @Szabolics: You wrote "In my opinion, for most uses casses it does not make sense to do an accurate conversion...the proper way ...is to specify an accuracy limit that is reasonable for the problem, i.e., use `Rationalize`."   Perhaps, but shouldn't that be my decision rather than the program's? Further, in cases where it does make sense to do an exact conversion, `Rationalize` doesn't allow you to specify an accuracy limit that is reasonable for the problem, since its "0" (in `Rationalize[a,0]` isn't really "0".

Comment: @theorist I don't understand your comment. What is it that you want to achieve that you cannot?  Also, as George above pointed out, `SetPrecision[x, Infinity]` does in fact give you the exact result.  What is then the problem?

Comment: @theorist I rephrased the answer. The problem is that your concept of exactness is flawed, and true exactness is not useful (or at least I do not see how it can be useful) unless you are concerned with the precise representation of floating point numbers.  If you want to study such representations, the ComputerArithmetic package is useful.

Comment: @Szabolics Why do you say `SetPrecision[a,Infinity]` gives the exact result? As I show in my question, SetPrecision[a, Infinity]` gives 6708329434841099/16777216, which is not exactly equal to 
 39984759300000068/100000000 = 399847593.00000068

Comment: @theorist As I explained in my answer, computers represent floating point numbers in binary, not decimal.  At this point people usually recommend reading https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Szabolcs   I'm not looking for exact representations of the computer's internal binary representation of floating points. Rather, I'm looking for exact rational representation of the numbers themselves (which the software can do, if I enter them manually), and I want such exact representations carried through the calculation to the end, at which point cancellations and numerical conversion can be done. Your assertion that my concept of exactness is flawed is thus incorrect, and seems to have resulted from a misunderstanding of my goal. I'll take a look at the ComputerArithmetic package.

Comment: @theorist "The numbers themselves" *are* exactly what the computer represents in binary.  If you mean the digits you enter, then it's a [duplicate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42141/enter-exact-rational-numbers-easily-with-decimal-notation).  But keep in mind that as soon as you evaluate `a=0.1`, the value of `a` is not `0.1` anymore but `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625`. Also, as soon as you enter a decimal point in Mathematica, you gave up any exactness.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple ideas:

```
Round[a, 10^-Round[Accuracy[a]]]
FromDigits @ RealDigits[a]
```

> 1999237965000003/5000000
>
> 1999237965000003/5000000

Comment: These fractions are not exactly equal to 39984759300000068/100000000 = 399847593.00000068

Comment: Note that the missing 8 is the 17th digit of a machine number (which only has 16 digits of precision).

Comment: you can do this:  ``Round[ 399847593.00000068`20, 10^-8]``

Comment: @george2079 That works!  But I'd like a way I can do this in a less manual fashion, without counting up the total number of digits and the total number after the decimal.  Also, why doesn't `Round[SetPrecision[399847593.00000068, 20], 10^-8]` give the same result?

Comment: the fundamental problem is whatever you key in gets "almost" instantly converted to a machine number, so if you key in more digits than a machine number can hold they are just lost.  See here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46169/2079 for an attempt at manipulating the keyed-in string before conversion.

Comment: Ah, so the reason the backtick works is that it's applied earlier than SetPrecision?  I'd be curious to learn when they're applied during input evaluation.

Comment: @theorist the backtick notation is part of the number representation and it affects the parsing of the input before evaluation takes place. But `SetPrecision` is not part of the number representation, it is a function which is applied during evaluation. When you enter `SetPrecision[399847593.00000068, 20]` the first thing that happens is the string of characters `399847593.00000068` gets interpreted as the machine precision number not quite equal to `39984759300000068/10^8`. The `SetPrecision` function never sees the string of digits you typed in, it sees that machine precision number.

Comment: I think essentially you are asking if you can enter exact numbers (rationals) using the notation for inexact numbers. The answer is no, except by intercepting the input string before it is parsed, as shown by george in the linked answer.

Comment: @SimonWoods  Yes, that's right.  And what you and george explained also nicely addresses my longstanding curiosity about why SetPrecision and backtick give different output, and why you can't use backtick with variables.  Thanks!